# Build Objectbox lib (libobjectbox.so) by myself

Tags: objectbox

for some reasons I need to build objectbox library by myself. But I cant find any information about this, only precompiled binaries. Is it possible?

I've downloaded src from https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-c/releases, but at the build process script downloaded "Pre-compiled ObjectBox library"

```
-- Using pre-compiled ObjectBox library v0.19.0 for linux-x64: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-c/releases/download/v0.19.0/objectbox-linux-x64.tar.gz
-- Pre-compiled ObjectBox library is saved in /_temp/objectbox-c-0.19.0/build-test/_deps/objectbox-download-src
-- Using pre-compiled ObjectBox-sync library v0.19.0 for linux-x64: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-c/releases/download/v0.19.0/objectbox-sync-linux-x64.tar.gz
-- Pre-compiled ObjectBox library is saved in /_temp/objectbox-c-0.19.0/build-test/_deps/objectbox-sync-download-src
```

Comment: The core ObjectBox libraries are only available as pre-built binaries. What are you trying to do? Maybe open an issue and we can find a solution. (Note: For business customers we can work something out if you need e.g. a special build.)